# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' with subprocess

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem when I try to launch my program with a subprocess. When I run it directly, without going through another file, there is no problem. I use Python 3.10 on Windows 10.

I also checked, the selenium module is up to date and installed in the same place as the python interpreter.

Thanks for your help.

```
player_list = get_size_player_list()
while player_list >= 1:
    try:
        # subprocess.call("get_data.py", shell=True)
        subprocess.call(["python3", "get_data.py"])
        player_list = get_size_player_list()
        sleep(15)
    except:
        print("Error we repeat the process")
        break
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgFGP.png)
[Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmkTr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
import sys

sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work :/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).